# KDE search shortcut action by shortcut keys

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, kde5

I'm trying KDE 5 and I'm spending significant amount of time looking at the System Setting shortcuts to find the name of the feature associated to a given key shortcut. Some shortcuts are interfering with some applications, where I cannot use the application feature I want because KDE have some feature associated with that shortcut.

Is there a way to search through KDE shortcuts list by the specific shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and it is straight in your face. Though, it might be slightly inconvenient to use if you do not know the name of the keys.

Lets say you want to search the shortcut associated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>; you open System Settings, then navigate to Shortcuts, and just type in the search bar: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

You will see the list of shortcuts filter by this regex.

tl;dr: In search, TYPE the key combo you want to find.

And, finally because a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: Keyboard shortcut search by keys]

On more information from the comment, what you want to change ISN'T a keyboard shortcut (which consists only of keyboard strokes), but a window behaviour (changing behaviour of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+*LClick* on a window). That is in Window Management.

Change the Left Click action to Nothing.

[image: Window Actions]

Comment: I know that, but it seems like it does not look for every possible key shortcut. My specific problem is with `Alt` key: when I'm using GIMP on Gnome, I use `Alt+Left Click` over a layer mask to show it on the screen. On KDE, the same key combination is intercepted by KDE making the entire application window semi-transparent, thus preventing me to display the layer mask. Looking for `Alt`, I cannot find what what could be causing it . Second example: the key `Meta` is used to open the Application Launcher, but if I search for `Meta` in the System Settings -> Shortcuts, nothing comes up...

Comment: It would also be helpful if you included the above comment as part of your question itself.

Comment: @Davide_sd Ahh, that's a very different thing. That might appear to be a shortcut, but it isn't. A keyboard shortcut IS composed ONLY of keyboard key presses. That's why you cannot find it there. For, it ISN'T a keyboard shortcut. What you want to change is a window behaviour, which is under Window Management -> Windows Behaviour -> Windows Actions (Tab); Inner Window, Titlebar and Frame.

Comment: Searching in the list of shortcuts does not work anymore in newer versions of KDE. Sadly it's one of many features I've seen gone missing in my time with KDE. I guess KDE is becoming another dumbed down Gnome desktop.